# How do I select all tables from a list in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I have my code here:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn_string = conn_str = pyodbc.connect(
    'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    'Server=server;'
    'Database=database;'
    'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )

select_all_tables_query = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'""", cnxn_string)
df_all_tables=pd.DataFrame(select_all_tables_query)

tables = df_all_tables['table_name']
for table in tables:
    sql_query=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
df=pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv(r'C:\path\{table}', index=False)
```

I am trying to select all tables, from the list of tables I pulled and put into a dataframe here:

> tables = df_all_tables['table_name']

and iterate through each table in 'tables' in my forloop. This would iterate through each table and write them to a csv, one by one. Well that's my logic anyway, clearly my code is wrong. I get the error:

```
pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM {table}': ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

When I try running it, this is how it runs and these are the outputs:

```
c:\path_to_python_file.py:19: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
c:\path_to_python_file.py:19: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
c:\path_to_python_file.py: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
  sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
```

I thought {table} will be replaced with the name of the table in my dataframe, nothing is being outputted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an f-string. It's currently querying literally for a table named `{table}`.

```
sql_query=pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {table}", cnxn_string)
```

For example:

```
var = 'foo'

# Prints {var}
print("{var}")

# Prints foo
print(f"{var}")
```

Comment: ah ok that was a silly mistake. i updated the my question with more info after i corrected my code